# JDOM - SaxBuilder - Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, jdom

I am having trouble parsing an XML file into a JDOM Document instance using the SAXBuilder.

It throws the following exception:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I have found and read all those threads on Stack Exchange and on other places in the Internet and tried various things to debug the error.

I have end up with the following code snippet, which throws as well.

```
String template = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<server></server>";
InputStream in = new StringBufferInputStream(template);
return saxBuilder.build(in);
```

What's wrong with it?

---

**I am ashamed to admit that but it turned out that the error wasn't produced by the snippet I have shown here but rather at a later point where I was comparing the parsed XML against another one using the XMLUnit library.**

The think that made me believe that the error was in the presented lines was the content of the error message.

I believe it would be appropriate to close (and delete, if that's possible) this question as it does not mean any value.

Comment: Do you really have the string or do you read a textfile / xml document from a file? In my experience, this error may occur if the file returns null for some reason and you do not actually build data.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means you have text before your xml declaration.

In your snippet the xml seems fine. The issue may not be in your document though. If you have a schema or other referenced xml file, the error could in fact refer to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is somewhere else. The following code (using [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)) works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
    String template = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<server></server>";
    SAXReader saxReader = new SAXReader();
    InputStream is = new StringBufferInputStream(template);
    Document document = saxReader.read(is);
    System.out.println(document.asXML());
}
```

Note also that `StringBufferInputStream` is deprecated. An alternative is

```
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(template);
        Document document = saxReader.read(sr);
```

So, the problem is not in your XML snippet, but probably in `saxBuilder.build(...)`

Comment: don't convert a String to bytes in order to parse it as XML, use a StringReader.